# How to clone the table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm a new in Microsoft SQL, so just lab with the database name "test" , and 1 table imported from excel named "dbo.Sheet1$", so i would like to clone the current table, I wrote the query script like below:

```
use test;
create table newtable as select * from dbo.Sheet1$
```

I got the message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Could you please help assist on this ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this

```
use test;

select * into newtable from dbo.Sheet1$
```

you can read more about SELECT INTO [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)